# Nuxt SSR DEV mode: proxyRequest does not work with node 19+ (works with 18)

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

This catch-all server middleware in my Nuxt 3 App works with Node 18:

> server/api/[...].ts

```
import { joinURL } from 'ufo';
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig();
    const path = event.path.replace(/^\/api\//, '');
    const target = joinURL(config.backendUrl, path);
    console.log('Proxy -->', target);
    return proxyRequest(event, target);
});
```

But when I use **Node 19.0.0 or higher, the console.log is executed but then the webapp does not load anymore**.

Replacing `proxyRequest(event, target);` with `return event;` solves the problem.

**This happens in DEV mode only. A production build works.** Any ideas?

UPDATE: A minimal reproduction with this server middleware with Node 19+ works as expected, so it must be something else in theApp. This is my nuxt config:

```
import svgLoader from 'vite-svg-loader';
import type { ConsentType } from './composables/useConsentControl';
import { ENV } from './constants/environments';

const autoImportDirs = ['constants', 'stores'];

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    telemetry: false,
    experimental: {
        // https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/pull/23725
        defaults: {
            useAsyncData: {
                deep: false,
            },
        },
    },
    components: [
        {
            path: '~/components',
            pathPrefix: false,
        },
    ],
    nitro: {
        imports: {
            dirs: autoImportDirs,
        },
        compressPublicAssets: {
            gzip: true,
            brotli: true,
        },
    },
    imports: {
        dirs: autoImportDirs,
    },
    vite: {
        plugins: [
            svgLoader({
                defaultImport: 'url',
            }),
        ],
    },
    css: ['@/assets/styles/main.scss'],
    devtools: { enabled: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_ENVIRONMENT !== ENV.PRODUCTION },
    modules: ['@vueuse/nuxt', '@pinia/nuxt', 'nuxt-jsonld', '@nuxt/image', '@zadigetvoltaire/nuxt-gtm', '@dargmuesli/nuxt-cookie-control'],
    pinia: {
        storesDirs: ['./stores/**', './ranking/**'],
    },
    image: {
        domains: ['https://static.ecommercedb.com'],
    },
    runtimeConfig: {
       baseUrl: process.env.NUXT_BASE_URL,
       // and many other env vars
    },
    public: {
       // many env vars
    },
},
}
```

Comment: The latest LTS version of Node is 20, pair versions are also the stable ones. Skip odd version numbers for stability reasons. Also, what version of Node is used in production?

Comment: The problem happens with any version higher than 19. In production we are using 18 lts, but I wanted to update that.